# SharePoint Online Sharing Options - Looking for a Way to Point to Native Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online

Dear Team i am looking for a way to Point this Outlook Option to Native "Desktop Outlook if you see the screenshot below where Outlook is shown that is as of now pointing to Web Outlook and we do not use web Based Outlook, So i would like to Point this to Native Outlook any help will be appreciated Thank you"

[image]

Comment: Could you modify the url of the icon? Change it to "mailto:tester@test.com"

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: This control isn't something you can customize.

Comment: Any Work Around?